# programmatically closing application on back key pressed event WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to close my Wp7 app when the back is pressed in emulator.I have tried the code on that page from which I would close the whole app.the code is given below:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        {
            while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
        }
    }
```

Help needed !
Thanks in advance!

Comment: **OnBackKeyPress** event is not firing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, There is no way to close wp7 application programatically.

And to do this you need not override back key press. When in the first page(ideally the home page or main page), pressing back key automatically closes the application.

Comment: Suppose, I have 3pages,named PageA,PageB and PageC. PageA is the start up page. I can navigate to PageB from PageA, then PageC from PageB. When I am in Page PageC, if I press back button, then it will not go back rather the whole app will be closed! 
Anyways...i have able to do this !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!this is how i did this:

`
private void Exit()
        {
            try
            {
                while (NavigationService.BackStack.Any())
                    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            catch { }
        }
`
see details : http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-exit-application.html